# Instantiate a type based on json and metadata using lift-json

Tags: java, generics, scala, reflection, lift-json

I would like to deserialise Scala case classes that have been serialised using lift-json.  The problem I am having is, I don't know how to invoke the generic method `extractOpt[A]` method below:

```
someString:String = {...}
JsonParser.parse(someString).extractOpt[A]
```

The type of `[A]` is going to depend on metadata, for example the class name of `[A]` but for the life of me I can't work out how to make the call using reflection.  In c# I would just be able to set the generic type for a call on `extractOpt[A]` using reflection.  I fear my problems are something to do with Java type erasure.

I am going to have a lot of case classes so I really want to avoid having to create some kind of hand crafted map from {metadata} -> classOf[].  I have full control over what the metadata associated with `someString` is.

If it helps understand *why* I have this issue, I am implementing event sourcing, and all my [A] types are going to be persisted events. Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val json:JValue = JsonParser.parse(someString)
//typeName = classCanonicalName, ie this is the metadata
val eventType = Class.forName(typeName) 
val deserialised:Event = Extraction.extract(json, TypeInfo(eventType,None)).asInstanceOf[Event]
```

And for bonus points, why does pressing the 'ask question' button on StackOverflow lead to you instantly being able to think of a solution to your own problem? ;)